# No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' - Tensorflow CPU version

Tags: tensorflow

While trying to upgrade to latest version of Tensorflow(1.8) i came across the below error. I am using windows 7 os and 64 bit system. python 3.6.0.

The worst part is i am facing the same issue even after downgrading to Tensorflow 1.7 which was working fine for me before. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Shekar.Selvaraj/PycharmProjects/OracleCategoryPrediction/OracleCategoryPredict/HTSNumberPredict/MachineLearningOracle/HTSClass.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Shekar.Selvaraj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowProj\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved, when i did conda install instead of pip.
Please use 'conda install tensorflow'. It should work.